Paint bubbling/discoloration in one corner of the basement?
New homeowners in the foothills north of Los Angeles.  About 3 months ago we first noticed there was some bubbling and discoloration to the painted cinderblocks in just one corner of the basement. There has been minimal further changes since then.



Is this a problem with a new coat of paint applied by the outgoing homeowners, or a more serious indication of leakage/water damage?

Have you had heavy rains recently? If so, I'd be inclined to think it's water infiltration. See if it gets worse -- take picture periodically to compare.

That's almost certainly caused by water / excessive moisture.

Definitely water damage, the lower pic shows effluorescence.
